# Error while Install the Google Client Library

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, composer-php, google-api-php-client

I'm going to working in google drive API and follow this link of google drive API

[Google api quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php)

1. Turn on the Drive API through the `Enable The Drive API` and successfully download the `credentials.json` and save him in my working directory.
2. when I'm going to `Install the Google Client Library` through the `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` its give me error like this type

[image: Screenshot of my Error "In which I Explain my error"]

So please help me in this error and thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Check if you have permissions to write into the directory where you execute `composer require` it will create the composer.json file for you, but the error says it can not write

Comment: then whats i can do reinstall the komodo software ?